# Connect to VM trough bastion with an SSH key in a private key vault

Tags: azure, azure-bastion

I am facing an issue when trying to connect to a VM using bastion. I want to use the SSH key that is stored in a keyvault (only accessible through a private endpoint).

The bastion, the VM and the keyvault are all in the same VNET.
The portal tells me `I don't have list access` but that is not true (Attached Image).
The private endpoint has a private dns entry and a private IP.
The private dns zone has a VNET-link to the VNET.

Is there something I am missing? Is this not the way to go?

[image]

Comment: Can you also provide a diagram of network connectivity with all the assets so its easier to imagine? you can use Visio for example